# Calling Java boolean function from XSLT

Tags: java, xslt

I'm calling a static Java function from XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:template name="has-special-characters">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="java:com.whatever.utils.PdfTemplatingUtils.hasSpecialCharacters($input)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which is okay and works.

Now, that java function that I'm calling returns a boolean. How can I test that boolean in XSLT? Does XSLT treat it as a String? I could change the return type of the function that I'm calling, but it makes sense to have it return a boolean, not a String or an int.

Thanks!

Comment: After a while I found out that it's mapped to a string in xslt, so I just had to do: test="$whatever = 'true'"

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use? And do you have the string instead of a boolean value directly after the function call or only after doing `<xsl:value-of select="java:foo.bar.myFunc()"/>` with XSLT? Remember that `xsl:value-of` always creates a text node.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that a Java boolean value is treated in XSLT/XPath has a boolean value as well so you should be able to use e.g. `<xsl:if test="java:foo.bar.myFunc()">...</xsl:if>`. But it all depends on the XSLT processor you use. So find out which XSLT processor you use and check its documentation on how Java and XSLT/XPath types are mapped.